# how to list files which are deleted in depot but opened in edit locally?

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

I am using p4 in linux. I was doing some changes to a file which was opened under edit in my local. When i tried submitting it, i found that the file has been deleted from the depot.

Is there some command in perforce which i can run and check if a file opened under edit in local has been deleted in the depot? Even some fancy one-liner would do.

Please note i am using an old version of perforce, so all the new fancy commands might not be available to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, hope it would be helpful for others

```
    ( find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 p4 fstat > /dev/null ) | & awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `p4 fstat my-file`.

If it says `headAction delete`, then the file is currently deleted in the depot.

If it says `action edit`, then you have the file open for edit.